# How to docstring attributes of a Python class inheriting from a dict?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, inheritance

If I create and document a regular class, it would look something like:

```
class Base:
    """A standalone base class.

    Parameters
    ----------
    param : string
        A simple parameter.

    Instance Attributes
    -------------------
    name : string
        A very important name.
    """
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.name = param
```

but if I inherit from a `dict`:

```
class Base(dict):
    """A child of dict.

    Parameters
    ----------
    param : string
        A simple parameter.

    Attributes?
    -----------
    key?
    value?
    """
    def __init__(self, param):
        self['Name'] = param
```

What do I have instead of attributes? What is the structure of docstrings like here? How does it relate to `__dict__` attributes? How does it change if I inherit from a `list`?